# How to generate analysis-sparse signals

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Let

$$\Omega = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \ldots \\
\ldots \\
\ldots & 0 & -1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times n}
$$

be a discrete finite difference operator and let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector. I now want to construct $x%$ in such a way that I can guarantee that $\Omega x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ has exactly $s \in \{0,\ldots,N-1\}$ zero rows.

What I have tried so far is to select a subset $S \subset \{0,\ldots,N-1\}, |S| = s$ and choose $\Omega_S$ as the submatrix consisting of these $s$ rows. Then I draw a standard normal vector $v$ and set 
$$x = v - \Omega_S^T (\Omega_S \Omega_S^T)^{-1} \Omega_Sv.$$

However, this procedure fails for higher sparsities. Is there any other way to generate these signals? 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to be able to decide which rows or should it be automatic in some sense?

Comment: It can be automatic, the only important part for now is the number of zero rows of $\Omega x$, not their location.

Comment: I know how I would try to do it but it may be a bit obscure without some introductory text. And I haven't written any such text yet because I have not had time. If you are ok with a probably difficult to understand answer I can write one.

Comment: Its worth a try!

Comment: Maybe it's worth a try, but not in my current shape. I go drink some tea and try to get this terrible headache go away. Maybe I can answer later this week or something.